# laravel5 Route::resource Generate wrong route

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.7 Route::resource.

I has saw
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/controllers
when I use

```
Route::resource('koumokus', 'KoumokuController');
```

should be Generate as bleow

```
GET admin/koumokus/{koumoku}        show
GET admin/koumokus/{koumoku}/edit   edit
```

However, It is Generate

```
GET admin/koumokus/{koumokus}       show
GET admin/koumokus/{koumokus}/edit  edit
```

on the other hand,

```
Route::resource('funruis', 'FunruiController');
```

is normally to gent

```
GET admin/funruis/{funrui}      show
GET admin/funruis/{funrui}/edit edit
```

[image]

How can I fixed it?

Comment: You can  set the parameters used, it's in the docs ... Naming resource route parameters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes laravel fails to find the conventional name for the parameter on the resource routes. It has happened to me sometimes when I used words that are not in english. But it allows you to customize that name. You can take a look at the docs here ->
[Naming Resource Route Parameters](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/controllers#restful-naming-resource-route-parameters)

Since you are working with the `'koumokus'` resource here, you can specify that the parameter for the `'koumokus'` resource must be `'koumoku'`.

```
Route::resource('koumokus', 'KoumokuController', [
    'parameters' => [
        'koumokus' => 'koumoku'
    ]
]);
```